# Navigate to Record page from related list in lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-record-page

I have a requirement where in i have over ridden the standard case button in contact related list. Now when i click 'New' in Case under contact related list a popup with few fields is opened but this takes to case tab and recordId of contact is lost,where in i want to redirect my page back to contact record page on click of any button in modal popup. Tried following approach but i am not getting recordId since page is navigating to case object.

```
Initial contact url--lightning/r/Contact/0035400000NIr0ZAAT/view

Case URL--lightning/o/Case/new?inContextOfRef=1.eyJ0eXBlIjoic3RhbmRhcmRfX3JlY29yZFBhZ2UiLCJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7InJlY29yZElkIjoiMDAzNTQwMDAwME5JcjBaQUFUIiwiYWN0aW9uTmFtZSI6InZ
```

> This code i am using for redirect to contact record page.

```
logFeedback:function(component){
    component.find("navId").navigate({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId : component.get("v.recordId"), // record id from given objectApiName
            actionName: 'view',
            objectApiName:'Contact'
        }}, true);
```

**But since record id is gone its not redirecting.**

```
Any other suggestions/alternative approach.
```

Comment: r u using visualforce/lightning out approach?

Comment: I am doing it through lightning component

Comment: that means you are trying to override the standard `New case` button, that's why it's  redirect to standard  case tab, by this approach you can't get the `contactid`. there is idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003TXFQA2 .   but you can achieve your use case by using visualforce-lightningout-custombutton

Answer (score 1):

that means you are trying to override the standard `New case` button, that's why it's  redirect to standard  case tab, by this approach you can not get the `contactid`. there is [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003TXFQA2)  .

but you can achieve your use case

> ```
> 1 .by using visualforce-lightningout-custombutton
> 2 . you can add custom action in record detail page like beside in `edit` button it 
>     opens your lightning component  then get contact id by using `force:hasRecordId` 
>     get record id
> ```

Comment: Hi can you please let me know how can i achieve this.

Comment: We added list button in related list using vf lightningOut but still it opens the lightning component in separate tab.

Comment: https://github.com/jmdohn/Quick-Actions-Everywhere